# What information can a competitor acquire from my Google Analytics account?

Tags: google-analytics

An ex-employee has gone over to a competitor, and it's been 3 weeks. I've realized not too long ago that this person still had shared access to the Master account...

Being that this person was the most proficient person in the office with GA, I'm sure information from the account has been shared.

What should I be expecting?

Any preventions to take so I don't get hacked?

Comment: I would be more concerned on what other info he might give them other than GA statistics. Not undermining the GA access issue.

Answer (score 1):

To stop further intrusions change all the passwords for GA and remove the individual from the shared access list.

To quote [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Analytics):

> "Google Analytics (GA) is a service offered by Google that generates
> detailed statistics about a website's traffic and traffic sources and
> measures conversions and sales."
>
> "GA can track visitors from all referrers, including search engines
> and social networks, direct visits and referring sites. It also
> displays advertising, pay-per-click networks, email marketing and
> digital collateral such as links within PDF documents."

Basically anyone who has access to your GA account can see the statistics for your website, including number of visitors, search keywords, page popularity and so on.